# Forming a matrix by summing 2 arrays element-array wise using NumPy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

Let's say I have the following NumPy arrays:

```
i = array([2, 4, 5])
j = array([0, 1, 2])
```

I would like to have a very efficient method (built-in if possible) to sum those vectors and have an output that looks like this:

```
[[2 4 5]
 [3 5 6]
 [4 6 7]]
```

So basically each column is the array j to which the k th element of i has been added (k = 0, 1, 2 in this case)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.add.outer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html).

```
>>> import numpy as np                                                                                                 
>>> i = np.array([2, 4, 5])                                                                                            
>>> j = np.array([0, 1, 2])                                                                                            
>>>                                                                                                                    
>>> np.add.outer(j, i)                                                                                                 
array([[2, 4, 5],
       [3, 5, 6],
       [4, 6, 7]])
```

Answer (score 3):

Or with `broadcasting`:

```
In [272]: i[:,None]+j
Out[272]: 
array([[2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [5, 6, 7]])
```

`i[:,None]` makes a `(3,1)` array, which broadcasts with a `(3,)` (or `(1,3)`) to make a `(3,3)`.

Comment: Heads up, I was recently scolded for using `None` over `np.newaxis`. ;)